# Swift: Can't figure out how to save how user left tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, nsuserdefaults

Using Swift 3

I've been working on a blog reader app for a while but I've been stuck on how to save the tableview like how the user left it.

The app works by me inputing data into the mysql database which is sent using php and received with json and swift 3 to populate the tableview. I expect to update this database everyday. There are two sections in the tableview, top one is followedArray and second is mainArray which is where all the objects are after being in jsonArray. When the user clicks the follow button, that single cell is moved into followedArray where the user can see the blog being updated and receive notifications.

I've tried using UserDefaults by saving the whole array into an object but it didn't work out as it was way to complicated creating the NSData objects using NSCoding, when there is no need to save the entire array (my guess).

**My question, is there a simple way that I can save how the user left the tableview?**

For example: In the 'All Objects Section' lets say I have 3 cells and the user clicks the follow button on 2 cells, those 2 cells are now in the 'Followed Section' with 1 cell in 'All Objects Section'. How do I save the state of this tableview. I want to save in which section the followed cell is in now and the changed button which is now a Followed Button instead of Follow Button (saving the hidden enabled code as I hide one button to show the other).

Do I use UserDefaults or CoreData? Maybe a CocoaPod library? Do I save the entire array or just which section its in and the .hidden code? How will updating and adding new objects affect it?

I'm fairly new to Swift so if you can help it would be appreciated. Any code that you need to understand how the app works, just ask for it as I don't know what code is necessary to show. I know you're not supposed to ask for code but if you can it would be great as I've been trying for months with no progress. Thank you!

Here is how I handle incoming json data:

MainController.swift

```
var jsonArray: NSMutableArray = []
var mainArray = [Blog]()
var followedArray = [Blog]()
var filteredArray = [Blog]()

// Title for Header
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    if !(searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "") {

        if section == 0 {
            return "Followed Blogs"
        }
        else {
            return "All Blogs"
        }
    }
    return "Filtered Blogs"
}

// Number of Rows in Section
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if !(searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "") {

        if section == 0 {

            return followedArray.count
        }
        else if (section == 1) {

            return mainArray.count
        }

    }
    return filteredArray.count

}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let CellIdentifier = "Cell"
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CellIdentifier) as! CustomCell

    if cell != cell {
        cell = CustomCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier)
    }

    // Configuring the cell
    var blogObject: Blog

    if !(searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "") {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            blogObject = followedArray[indexPath.row] 
            cell.populateCell(blogObject, isFollowed: true, indexPath: indexPath, parentView: self)
        }
        else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            blogObject = mainArray[indexPath.row] 
            cell.populateCell(blogObject, isFollowed: false, indexPath: indexPath, parentView: self)
        }
    }
    else {
        blogObject = filteredArray[indexPath.row] 
        cell.populateCell(blogObject, isFollowed: false, indexPath: indexPath, parentView: self)
    }

    return cell
}

@IBAction func followButtonClick(_ sender: UIButton!) {

    // Adding row to tag
    let buttonPosition = (sender as AnyObject).convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.myTableView)
    if let indexPath = self.myTableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition) {

        // Showing Status Labels
        let cell = self.myTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.firstStatusLabel.isHidden = false
        cell.secondStatusLabel.isHidden = false

        // Change Follow to Following
        (sender as UIButton).setImage(UIImage(named: "follow.png")!, for: .normal)
        cell.followButton.isHidden = true
        cell.followedButton.isHidden = false

        // Checking wether to import from mainArray or filteredArray to followedArray
        if !(searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "") {

            self.myTableView.beginUpdates()

            // ----- Inserting Cell to followedArray -----
            followedArray.insert(mainArray[indexPath.row], at: 0)
            myTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .fade)

            // ----- Removing Cell from mainArray -----
            mainArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            let rowToRemove = indexPath.row
            self.myTableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: rowToRemove, section: 1)], with: .fade)

            self.myTableView.endUpdates()

            myTableView.reloadData()
        }
        else {

            self.myTableView.beginUpdates()

            // ----- Inserting Cell to followedArray -----
            let blogObject: Blog = filteredArray[indexPath.row]
            let indexOfObjectInArray = mainArray.index(of: blogObject)

            followedArray.insert(blogObject, at: 0)

            // ----- Removing Cell from filteredArray -----
            filteredArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            blogArray.remove(at: indexOfObjectInArray!)
            let rowToRemove = indexPath.row
            self.myTableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: rowToRemove, section: 0)], with: .fade)

            self.myTableView.endUpdates()

            myTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

func retrieveDataFromServer() {

    let getDataURL = "http://exampleblog.com/receiving.php"
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: getDataURL)!

    do {

        let data: Data = try Data(contentsOf: url as URL)
        jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSMutableArray

        // Looping through jsonArray
        for i in 0..<jsonArray.count {

            // Create Blog Object
            let bID: String = (jsonArray[i] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "id") as! String
            let bName: String = (jsonArray[i] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "blogName") as! String
            let bStatus1: String = (jsonArray[i] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "blogStatus1") as! String
            let bStatus2: String = (jsonArray[i] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "blogStatus2") as! String
            let bURL: String = (jsonArray[i] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "blogURL") as! String
            // New
            let bType: String = (jsonArray[i] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "blogType") as! String
            let bDate: String = (jsonArray[i] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "blogDate") as! String
            let bPop: String = (jsonArray[i] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "blogPop") as! String

            // Add Blog Objects to mainArray
            mainArray.append(Blog(blogName: bName, andBlogStatus1: bStatus1, andBlogStatus2: bStatus2, andBlogURL: bURL, andBlogID: bID, andBlogType: bType, andBlogDate: bDate, andBlogPop: bPop))

        }
    }
    catch {
        print("Error: (Retrieving Data)")
    }

    myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

CustomCell.swift - How the cells are being populated`enter code here`

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var firstStatusLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var secondStatusLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var followButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var followedButton: UIButton!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    self.followButton.isHidden = true
    self.followedButton.isHidden = true
}

func populateCell(_ blogObject: Blog, isFollowed: Bool, indexPath: IndexPath, parentView: Any) {

    // Loading Status Labels
    self.firstStatusLabel.text = blogObject.blogStatus1
    self.secondStatusLabel.text = blogObject.blogStatus2
    self.firstStatusLabel.isHidden = true
    self.secondStatusLabel.isHidden = true

    if isFollowed {
        self.followedButton.tag = indexPath.row
        self.followedButton.addTarget(parentView, action: #selector(MainController.followedButtonClick(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        self.followedButton.isHidden = false
        self.followButton.isHidden = true

        // Status Labels
        self.firstStatusLabel.isHidden = false
        self.secondStatusLabel.isHidden = false

    }
    else {
        self.followButton.tag = indexPath.row
        self.followButton.addTarget(parentView, action: #selector(MainController.followButtonClick(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        self.followedButton.isHidden = true
        self.followButton.isHidden = false

        // Status Labels
        self.firstStatusLabel.isHidden = true
        self.secondStatusLabel.isHidden = true

    }
}
}
```

Blog.swift

```
class Blog: NSObject {

// Strings
var blogName: String?
var blogStatus1: String?
var blogStatus2: String?
var blogURL: String?
var blogID: String?
var blogType: String?
var blogDate: String?
var blogPop: String?

override init() {

}

// Converting Strings into Objects
init(blogName bName: String,
     andBlogStatus1 bStatus1: String,
     andBlogStatus2 bStatus2: String,
     andBlogURL bURL: String,
     andBlogID bID: String,
     andBlogType bType: String,
     andBlogDate bDate: String,
     andBlogPop bPop: String)
{
    super.init()

    self.blogName = bName
    self.blogStatus1 = bStatus1
    self.blogStatus2 = bStatus2
    self.blogURL = bURL
    self.blogID = bID
    self.blogType = bType
    self.blogDate = bDate
    self.blogPop = bPop
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of different ways to accomplish what you want, both storing the information locally or remotely. If the blog ids are unique, you could store them in the defaults as an array of strings:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(followedBlogIds, forKey: "followedBlogIds")
```

You can then grab them anytime, just make sure to unwrap/cast them appropriately:

```
if let storedBlogIds = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "followedBlogIds") as? [String] {
    //filter your blogs by id and put them in the appropriate
    //arrays for your table
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this but UserDefaults only allows regular arrays not the kind of array that I'm using in mainArray, or am I wrong?

Comment: you are right - forgot you were limited to plist items! guess you do have to go the NSCoding route to use defaults to store the blogs directly. Editing with a different solution using user defaults

Comment: Thats smart using the blogIds, they are unique. How can use the ids to display the array. How would I go about this?

Comment: in your retrieveDataFromServer method, just check to see if the blog id matches any of the stored ids. if so append it to the followedArray instead of the main array